# Average prime value in n factorial.

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, analytic-number-theory

I was wondering about the (weighted) average prime value in the factorisation of $n!$. $\\$
 If we call $f(n)$ the average prime value in $n!$, then $f$ seems to increase rather linear.

Is there a clear explanation for that? Anything known about asymptotic behavior? I know that the number of primes smaller then $x$ is approximately $x/\log(x)$ 
, but here im somewhat intrigued. A friend made a plot for me of $f(n)$. 
Check the following link:

EDIT: Since my question wasnt clear to everyone: I meant the weighted average of primes. I mean explicitly the fraction $$\frac{\sum_{p\leq n}p \sum_{k\geq 1}{[n/p^k]}}{\sum_{p\leq n}\sum_{k\geq 1}[n/p^k]} $$

https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?q=smlmgo

Thanks for any suggestions in advance.

Comment: [the number of primes $< x$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem) is $\sim \frac{x}{\log x}$, and I don't get the rest

Comment: Asking what the "average prime value in the factorization of n!" is the exact same question as "average prime value of all primes less than n".

Comment: @r12: no, because smaller primes are weighted more heavily.  There are lots more factors of $2$ in $n!$ than there are factors of, say, $7$.  As $n$ becomes large, there are six times as many.

Comment: and the greatest prime in the factorization of $n!$ is the greatest prime $\le n$ and is $> n - C(\epsilon) n^{\epsilon}$ for any $\epsilon > 0$ and some constant $C$ depending on $\epsilon$  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_gap . but for finding the mean value, we'll need looking at $\displaystyle\frac{\sum_{p < x} p}{\sum_{p < x} 1}$ which is $\displaystyle\sim \frac{x^2 / \log(x)}{x / \log x} = x$

Comment: I suggest you write your question differently.  It's not immediately obvious what you're asking.  Maybe use more line breaks?  The example you give looks like just a jumble of integers.  Also, the link you gave doesn't do anything for me.  Maybe just include an image, instead?  Also, you need to share what progress you've already made.  Have you looked at the wikipedia page about the prime number theorem?  What is missing on that page that you need in order to do your work?  The body of work regarding prime counting is pretty expansive; I suspect you'd be able to find something.

Comment: now if we consider the weighted mean value, counting the multiplicity, it will be different. $\displaystyle  n! = \prod_{p \le n} p^{\sum_k \lfloor n / p^k \rfloor}$ hence the weighted mean value of the primes in the factorization of $n!$ is $\displaystyle \frac{\sum_{p \le n} p \sum_k \lfloor n / p^k \rfloor }{\sum_{p^k \le n} \lfloor n / p^k\rfloor} \sim \ldots$

Comment: Lol, r12. Its just a question out of curiosity. Nothing more, nothing less. Yes, i meant exactly weighted mean value. Sorry if that was not clear at first. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More a comment than an answer and lots of handwaving here, but I think it is OK.  As $n$ becomes large, a prime $p$ will divide $n!$ about $\frac n{p-1}$ times. It will never reach that fraction, but will converge on it from below.  There is a switch in the order of limits here that I have not justified, but then you are asking about $$\frac {\sum p_i\frac n{p_i-1}}{\sum \frac n{p_i-1}}$$ where the sums are taken over the primes $p_i$up to some limit.  Now we can divide out the $n$ and concentrate on the primes.  This presumes that the ratio is not perturbed too much by the fact that the larger primes have not approached their limiting density as well as the smaller ones.  I think this is the biggest threat to the argument.  We know that $p_i \approx i(\log i + \log (\log (i))-1)$ so this becomes the study of the asymptotics of $$\frac {\sum i(\log i + \log (\log (i))-1)\frac 1{i(\log i + \log (\log (i))-1)-1}}{\sum \frac 1{i(\log i + \log (\log (i))-1)-1}}$$  I couldn't get Alpha to help, but someone with Mathematica will find this easy.  I hope this prompts somebody to work on it further.

Added:  Daniel Fischer shows in a comment that this leads to the average being approximately $$\dfrac{n}{(\log n)(\log\log n)}$$

Comment: You make some very interesting observations there. How do you get the observation that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}[n/p^k] \approx  n/(p-1)$ ? Hmm...So it's even hard from that nice fraction to decide if its limiting behavior is linear.

Comment: @DinkyDoe $[n/p^k]\approx n/p^k$ and then you just have geometric progression.

Comment: Ah, thank you very kindly. Good point.

Comment: At the point where you replace $\sum \lfloor n/p_i^k\rfloor$ with $\frac{n}{p_i-1}$, you have a simpler continuation. You can cancel the $n$, and then write $p_i\frac{1}{p_i-1} = 1 + \frac{1}{p_i-1}$ in the numerator to see $$\frac{\sum p_i\frac{n}{p_i-1}}{\sum \frac{n}{p_i-1}} = 1 + \frac{\pi(n)}{\sum \frac{1}{p_i-1}}.$$ By Mertens' second theorem the denominator is $\log \log n + C + o(1)$. For larger $n$ the constant is negligible and we get the asymptotic behaviour of $\dfrac{\pi(n)}{\log \log n} \sim \dfrac{n}{(\log n)(\log\log n)}$.

Comment: In replacing $\sum \lfloor n/p_i^k\rfloor$ with $\frac{n}{p_i-1}$, you have a larger error for the larger primes, but that makes no difference for the asymptotics, I think.

Comment: @DanielFischer: yes, I worry about the error with larger primes.  That is what I was thinking about when I talked about switching limits.  I let $n$ go large before $p_i$, but of course then there are more primes to account for.

Comment: Let's see. For $p \leqslant \sqrt{n}$, we have $\frac{n}{p} < \sum \lfloor n/p^k\rfloor < \frac{n}{p-1}$. For $\sqrt{n} < p \leqslant n$ we have $v_p(n!) = \lfloor n/p\rfloor \leqslant \frac{n}{p}$. If we use $\frac{n}{p}$ for the primes $> \sqrt{n}$ and $\frac{n}{p-1}$ for the small primes, we get $$\frac{\pi(\sqrt{n}) + \sum_{p^2 \leqslant n} \frac{1}{p-1} + \sum_{n < p^2\leqslant n^2} \frac{1}{p}}{\sum_{p^2 \leqslant n} \frac{1}{p-1} + \sum_{n < p^2\leqslant n^2} \frac{1}{p}} \sim \frac{\pi(\sqrt{n})}{\log \log n},$$ which is a different behaviour.

Comment: If we take $n/p$ for all, we get $\pi(n)/\log \log n$ again. So it's more delicate than I thought.